# Angular 1.2 to 1.3 modals not work, unknown provider

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have a problem :D The problem is, now Im using angular 1.2 and last week I tried to update it to 1.3. Now I have a problems with modals. It is causing bcs of this 1.3 things.. My browser says,

> Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- mainCtrl

Bcs Im trying to make it like this,

```
angular.module('newApp').controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'applicationService', 'quickViewService', 'builderService', 'pluginsService', '$location', '$uibModal',
function($scope, applicationService, quickViewService, builderService, pluginsService, $location, $uibModal) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        applicationService.init();
        quickViewService.init();
        builderService.init();
        pluginsService.init();
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    });
```

I know this is not right.. I experienced it :D But how can I fix it ? I looked at the examples but didnt understand. Thank you so much. You are awesome!

Comment: Browser version? Post the complete code if you can And a working jfiddle

Comment: you do not inject ui.bootstrap in jsfiddle example. is it exact copy of your application???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using ui-bootstrap 0.12.1. There is no $uibModal service in that version. Here is [the documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.1/#/modal) for the modal directive in that version. The directives and services were all renamed with the `uib` prefix in version 0.14.0, as [the change log](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) shows.

Comment: Updating is a good idea. But why update to a version that is already obsolete? Udate to the latest version, and enjoy all the bug fixes and improvements that have been made since 1.3.